# Firefox 3D CSS Limitations: Z-order breaks with many elements

Tags: css, firefox, css-transforms

I have been working on an experiment where I take a small grayscale heightmap and turn it into a 3D terrain using cubes from `<div>` elements and CSS transformations.

The result can be seen on this [codepen](http://codepen.io/independent-software/pen/QKgvZx) and more details [here](http://www.independent-software.com/firefox-3d-css-limitations-maximum-element-count-and-close-positioning/). Or in the snippet here:

```css
body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: #000;
 color: #fff;
}

#terrain-view {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 perspective: 820px;
}

#terrain {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%; 
  top: 50%;
 width: 10em;
 height: 10em;
 margin-left: -5em;
 margin-top: -5em;
 transform: rotateX(80deg) rotateZ(170deg);
 font-size: 3em;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 border: solid 2px grey;
 animation: rotate 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
 0% {
  transform: rotateX(70deg) rotateZ(0deg);
 }
 100% {
  transform: rotateX(70deg) rotateZ(359deg);
 }
}

.cube {
 position: absolute;
 width: 1em;
 height: 1em;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 border: solid 1px #fff;
}

.side {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.top {
 background: green;
}

.front {
 background: yellow; 
 transform-origin: 50% 100% 0;
 transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(180deg);
}

.right {
 background: red;
 transform-origin: 100% 50% 0;
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateX(180deg); 
}

.left {
 background: blue;
 transform-origin: 0 50% 0;
 transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(180deg);
}

.back {
 background: brown; 
 transform-origin: 50% 0 0;
 transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(180deg);
 
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id="terrain-view">
    <div id="terrain">
     <div class="cube" style="left: 0em; top: 0em; transform: translateZ(0.09em) scaleZ(0.09);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 1em; top: 0em; transform: translateZ(0.28em) scaleZ(0.28);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 2em; top: 0em; transform: translateZ(0.5em) scaleZ(0.5);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 3em; top: 0em; transform: translateZ(0.87em) scaleZ(0.87);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 4em; top: 0em; transform: translateZ(1em) scaleZ(1);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 5em; top: 0em; transform: translateZ(1em) scaleZ(1);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 6em; top: 0em; transform: translateZ(0.87em) scaleZ(0.87);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 7em; top: 0em; transform: translateZ(0.5em) scaleZ(0.5);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 8em; top: 0em; transform: translateZ(0.28em) scaleZ(0.28);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 9em; top: 0em; transform: translateZ(0.09em) scaleZ(0.09);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 0em; top: 1em; transform: translateZ(0.28em) scaleZ(0.28);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 1em; top: 1em; transform: translateZ(0.73em) scaleZ(0.73);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 2em; top: 1em; transform: translateZ(1.12em) scaleZ(1.12);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 3em; top: 1em; transform: translateZ(1.62em) scaleZ(1.62);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 4em; top: 1em; transform: translateZ(1.77em) scaleZ(1.77);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 5em; top: 1em; transform: translateZ(1.77em) scaleZ(1.77);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 6em; top: 1em; transform: translateZ(1.62em) scaleZ(1.62);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 7em; top: 1em; transform: translateZ(1.12em) scaleZ(1.12);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 8em; top: 1em; transform: translateZ(0.73em) scaleZ(0.73);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 9em; top: 1em; transform: translateZ(0.28em) scaleZ(0.28);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 0em; top: 2em; transform: translateZ(0.5em) scaleZ(0.5);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 1em; top: 2em; transform: translateZ(1.12em) scaleZ(1.12);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 2em; top: 2em; transform: translateZ(1.77em) scaleZ(1.77);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 3em; top: 2em; transform: translateZ(2.26em) scaleZ(2.26);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 4em; top: 2em; transform: translateZ(2.39em) scaleZ(2.39);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 5em; top: 2em; transform: translateZ(2.39em) scaleZ(2.39);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 6em; top: 2em; transform: translateZ(2.26em) scaleZ(2.26);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 7em; top: 2em; transform: translateZ(1.77em) scaleZ(1.77);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 8em; top: 2em; transform: translateZ(1.12em) scaleZ(1.12);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 9em; top: 2em; transform: translateZ(0.5em) scaleZ(0.5);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 0em; top: 3em; transform: translateZ(0.87em) scaleZ(0.87);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 1em; top: 3em; transform: translateZ(1.62em) scaleZ(1.62);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 2em; top: 3em; transform: translateZ(2.26em) scaleZ(2.26);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 3em; top: 3em; transform: translateZ(2.52em) scaleZ(2.52);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 4em; top: 3em; transform: translateZ(2.55em) scaleZ(2.55);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 5em; top: 3em; transform: translateZ(2.55em) scaleZ(2.55);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 6em; top: 3em; transform: translateZ(2.52em) scaleZ(2.52);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 7em; top: 3em; transform: translateZ(2.26em) scaleZ(2.26);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 8em; top: 3em; transform: translateZ(1.62em) scaleZ(1.62);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 9em; top: 3em; transform: translateZ(0.87em) scaleZ(0.87);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 0em; top: 4em; transform: translateZ(1em) scaleZ(1);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 1em; top: 4em; transform: translateZ(1.77em) scaleZ(1.77);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 2em; top: 4em; transform: translateZ(2.39em) scaleZ(2.39);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 3em; top: 4em; transform: translateZ(2.55em) scaleZ(2.55);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 4em; top: 4em; transform: translateZ(2.55em) scaleZ(2.55);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 5em; top: 4em; transform: translateZ(2.55em) scaleZ(2.55);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 6em; top: 4em; transform: translateZ(2.55em) scaleZ(2.55);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 7em; top: 4em; transform: translateZ(2.39em) scaleZ(2.39);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 8em; top: 4em; transform: translateZ(1.77em) scaleZ(1.77);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 9em; top: 4em; transform: translateZ(1em) scaleZ(1);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 0em; top: 5em; transform: translateZ(1em) scaleZ(1);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 1em; top: 5em; transform: translateZ(1.77em) scaleZ(1.77);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 2em; top: 5em; transform: translateZ(2.39em) scaleZ(2.39);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 3em; top: 5em; transform: translateZ(2.55em) scaleZ(2.55);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 4em; top: 5em; transform: translateZ(2.55em) scaleZ(2.55);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 5em; top: 5em; transform: translateZ(2.55em) scaleZ(2.55);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 6em; top: 5em; transform: translateZ(2.55em) scaleZ(2.55);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 7em; top: 5em; transform: translateZ(2.39em) scaleZ(2.39);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 8em; top: 5em; transform: translateZ(1.77em) scaleZ(1.77);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 9em; top: 5em; transform: translateZ(1em) scaleZ(1);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 0em; top: 6em; transform: translateZ(0.87em) scaleZ(0.87);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 1em; top: 6em; transform: translateZ(1.62em) scaleZ(1.62);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 2em; top: 6em; transform: translateZ(2.26em) scaleZ(2.26);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 3em; top: 6em; transform: translateZ(2.52em) scaleZ(2.52);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 4em; top: 6em; transform: translateZ(2.55em) scaleZ(2.55);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 5em; top: 6em; transform: translateZ(2.55em) scaleZ(2.55);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 6em; top: 6em; transform: translateZ(2.52em) scaleZ(2.52);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 7em; top: 6em; transform: translateZ(2.26em) scaleZ(2.26);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 8em; top: 6em; transform: translateZ(1.62em) scaleZ(1.62);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 9em; top: 6em; transform: translateZ(0.87em) scaleZ(0.87);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 0em; top: 7em; transform: translateZ(0.5em) scaleZ(0.5);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 1em; top: 7em; transform: translateZ(1.12em) scaleZ(1.12);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 2em; top: 7em; transform: translateZ(1.77em) scaleZ(1.77);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 3em; top: 7em; transform: translateZ(2.26em) scaleZ(2.26);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 4em; top: 7em; transform: translateZ(2.39em) scaleZ(2.39);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 5em; top: 7em; transform: translateZ(2.39em) scaleZ(2.39);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 6em; top: 7em; transform: translateZ(2.26em) scaleZ(2.26);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 7em; top: 7em; transform: translateZ(1.77em) scaleZ(1.77);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 8em; top: 7em; transform: translateZ(1.12em) scaleZ(1.12);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 9em; top: 7em; transform: translateZ(0.5em) scaleZ(0.5);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 0em; top: 8em; transform: translateZ(0.28em) scaleZ(0.28);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 1em; top: 8em; transform: translateZ(0.73em) scaleZ(0.73);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 2em; top: 8em; transform: translateZ(1.12em) scaleZ(1.12);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 3em; top: 8em; transform: translateZ(1.62em) scaleZ(1.62);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 4em; top: 8em; transform: translateZ(1.77em) scaleZ(1.77);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 5em; top: 8em; transform: translateZ(1.77em) scaleZ(1.77);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 6em; top: 8em; transform: translateZ(1.62em) scaleZ(1.62);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 7em; top: 8em; transform: translateZ(1.12em) scaleZ(1.12);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 8em; top: 8em; transform: translateZ(0.73em) scaleZ(0.73);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 9em; top: 8em; transform: translateZ(0.28em) scaleZ(0.28);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 0em; top: 9em; transform: translateZ(0.09em) scaleZ(0.09);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 1em; top: 9em; transform: translateZ(0.28em) scaleZ(0.28);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 2em; top: 9em; transform: translateZ(0.5em) scaleZ(0.5);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 3em; top: 9em; transform: translateZ(0.87em) scaleZ(0.87);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 4em; top: 9em; transform: translateZ(1em) scaleZ(1);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 5em; top: 9em; transform: translateZ(1em) scaleZ(1);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 6em; top: 9em; transform: translateZ(0.87em) scaleZ(0.87);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 7em; top: 9em; transform: translateZ(0.5em) scaleZ(0.5);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 8em; top: 9em; transform: translateZ(0.28em) scaleZ(0.28);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div><div class="cube" style="left: 9em; top: 9em; transform: translateZ(0.09em) scaleZ(0.09);"><div class="side top"></div><div class="side front"></div><div class="side left"></div><div class="side right"></div><div class="side back"></div></div>   </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

On Chrome everything works fine. However, on Firefox, the Z-order of the elements breaks as soon as I have more than around 16 cubes (or 80 divs, since each cube consists of 5 divs).

**Is there a limit to the number of elements you can transform on Firefox? Or, did I omit something important in my CSS for Firefox?**

As a side question, on Firefox (but not Chrome), having two divs share the same 3D space (i.e. touch) will also break the Z-order and cause flickering. It appears the only way around this is introducing spacing between the divs, but that means I'll have to add spacing between the cubes which is ugly.

Comment: It is strange for you open bounty after that long time while it doesn't seem to have problem in firefox 61. You should ask Firefox if this is just a old bug.

Comment: Have you tested this on newest version of Firefox?

Comment: it's old question. it's all working in Firefox Developer Edition `62.0b19` and you might need to upgrade your firefox. why don't you give bounty points to someone and let someone enjoys with points.